# Error: The value 'null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext' because 'BuildContext' is not nullable

Tags: flutter, frameworks

i got this error when trying to run my flutter project:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMhqx.png)

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher_web-2.0.12/lib/src/link.dart:213:30: Error: The value 'null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext' because 'BuildContext' is not nullable.

- 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  pushRouteNameToFramework(null, routeName);

[framework.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJKa9.png)

so basically buildcontext is not nullable but this dart file is part of the framework.

also heres my flutter doctor:
[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CWF1.png)

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

If that doesn't work go for a:

```
flutter pub cache repair
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to degrade the `url_launcher` package to version 5.7.10: `url_launcher: ^5.7.10` to make it work.